Decreasing ctc loss during model training
I am handwriting recognition model during the training process i am encountering high ctc loss during training process what should i do to reduce the loss and to make my model recognize any text because as of now it cannot recognize anything.
link to Google-collab notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16VDTTcCGsQrpURZXCxL5695jZ5Xxze4O?usp=sharing[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/GswZOriQ.jpg)enter image description herehttps://colab.research.google.com/drive/16VDTTcCGsQrpURZXCxL5695jZ5Xxze4O?usp=sharing
def ctc_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    """
    Compute the CTC loss between true labels and predicted outputs.

    Args:
        y_true: Ground-truth labels (int32/int64).
        y_pred: Model predictions (logits).

    Returns:
        Mean CTC loss across the batch.
    """
    # Ensure y_true is of integer type
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, dtype=tf.int32)

    input_length = tf.fill([tf.shape(y_pred)[0]], tf.shape(y_pred)[1])  # Time steps
    label_length = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(y_true != -1, tf.int32), axis=1)  # Non-padding label lengths

    # Compute CTC loss
    loss = tf.nn.ctc_loss(
        labels=y_true,
        logits=y_pred,
        label_length=label_length,
        logit_length=input_length,
        blank_index=-1,  # Specify the blank index used for padding
        logits_time_major=False  # Logits are batch-major
    )

    return tf.reduce_mean(loss)

# Optimizer with Learning Rate Scheduler
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate=1e-3,
    decay_steps=10000,
    decay_rate=0.9
)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule, clipnorm=1.0)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=ctc_loss)

# Model Training
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

# Visualize Loss
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.title("Training and Validation Loss")
plt.xlabel("Epoch")
plt.ylabel("Loss")
plt.show()

I have tried using learn rate scheduler to lower the loss rate but it didn't work. Please correct my code and suggest improvements to fix the training process
